# Simplify multiple subqueries in UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, flarum

I want to make my [Flarum](http://flarum.org) forum update its discussion records after manual intervention into the database. (Flarum is still in beta and still lacks many features, so fixing things manually isn't that uncommon.) I managed to compose the following query which does what I wanted:

```
UPDATE discussions as d SET
  d.start_time =
    (SELECT min(p.time) FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id),
  d.last_time =
    (SELECT max(p.time) FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id),
  d.comments_count =
    (SELECT count(*) FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id AND p.type = 'comment'),
  d.participants_count =
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT p.user_id) FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id),
  d.start_post_id =
    (SELECT p.id FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id
         ORDER BY p.number ASC LIMIT 1),
  d.start_user_id =
    (SELECT p.user_id FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id
         ORDER BY p.number ASC LIMIT 1),
  d.last_post_id =
    (SELECT p.id FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id
         ORDER BY p.number DESC LIMIT 1),
  d.last_post_number =
    (SELECT p.number FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id
         ORDER BY p.number DESC LIMIT 1),
  d.last_user_id =
    (SELECT p.user_id FROM posts as p
         WHERE p.discussion_id = d.id
         ORDER BY p.number DESC LIMIT 1);
```

but it looks pretty ugly. I'm sure there is a way to write the same logic in a much more concise and efficient way, but I'm not really into SQL to know how to do it. Could someone tell me how to eliminate these almost duplicated subqueries?

The above mentioned tables definition is the following (with some details omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE discussions (
  id                   int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title                varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  comments_count       int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  participants_count   int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  number_index         int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  start_time           datetime NOT NULL,
  start_user_id        int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  start_post_id        int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  last_time            datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  last_user_id         int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  last_post_id         int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  last_post_number     int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  ... );

CREATE TABLE posts (
  id                   int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  discussion_id        int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  number               int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  time                 datetime NOT NULL,
  user_id              int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  type                 varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  ... );
```

Flarum uses MySQL as its primary storage backend, so MySQL-specific solution would be fine. However, it would be great if someone knows how to solve the problem in ANSI-SQL.

Comment: There is no shortcut to what you want. You have to do this way only i guess.  But I would love to see if it can happen.

Comment: @firegurafiku...I see you edited this post. Do you still need a solution nearly two years later?

Comment: @Parfait, if only out of curiosity. I just look after my questions when I can. Fix typos, for example :).

Comment: Why didn't you accept below answer?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a inner join and use max and min for first and last

```
UPDATE discussions as d 
INNER JOIN posts as p on d.id = p.discussion_id
SET d.start_time = min(p.time),
    d.last_time = max(p.time),
    d.comments_count = count(*),
    d.participants_count = count(DISTINCT p.user_id) ,
    d.start_post_id = min(p.id ),
    d.start_user_id = min(p.user_id  ),
    d.last_post_id =  max(  p.id ),
    d.last_post_number = max( p.number ),
    d.last_user_id = max( p.user_id  ),
    d.comments_count = sum( case when p.type = 'comment' then 1 else 0)
GROUP BY d.id
```

Comment: I think it won't work as desired. Firstly you are changing the schema of the table 'discussions'

Comment: i have changed  nothings .. i  have simply refactored  the query using .. sql  features ..like required  by OP

Comment: Looks promising! But I cannot get how `d.last_post_id =  min( d.last_post_id )` is going to work here. MySQL issues *“Error: Invalid use of group function”* message about it.

Comment: @firegurafiku   . could be  that you should intechange the max and min (i have not your data sample) but  the concept is easy .. select  order by col asc limit 1 is equals to mix(col) and for oreder desc limit 1 is equal to max  so  .. anyway  .. i have update the answer .. set (hope )correctly the min and the max

Comment: Ops ..( i have copied the wrong cols)  answer  updated with p.*  cols ..

Comment: @scaisEdge: Okay, got the `p.***` issue. But `d.last_post_id =  max(p.id )` still isn't correct as I need to find the row with maximum `p.number` within a discussion, and return `p.id` instead of the number.

Comment: @firegurafiku    you need the result grouped by d.id .. i think  .. i have update the answer